# ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object> Order by KEY Value for ListView Cells

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView that displays Time and Date and a bit of other information that's irrelevant to the issue. They are stored in an ArrayList Hashmap. When loaded into the ListView they are Organized by there ID's by default, Instead they need to be organized by the date and time. This is my code so far.

```
public void loadListView() {
   productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    List<SalesCall> salescall = db.getAllSalescalls();
    lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);
    for (SalesCall cn : salescall) {
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put(KEY_ID, cn.getID());
        map.put(KEY_NAME, cn.getDoctor());
        map.put(KEY_TIME, cn.getScheduled_time());
        map.put(KEY_DATE, cn.getScheduled_Date());
        map.put(KEY_ALL, cn.getAccount() + ":" + cn.getDoctor());
       productsList.add(map);

    }

    adapter = new ExtendedSimpleAdapter(
            getActivity(), productsList,
            R.layout.listview_item_layout_salescall,
            new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_TIME, KEY_DATE, KEY_ALL},
            new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.fname, R.id.Time, R.id.Date, R.id.All});
    // updating listview

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    db.close();
}
```

How would I sort the data Accordingly?

Edit: 
Comparable code

```
  @Override
      public int compare(SalesCall lhs, SalesCall rhs) {
        if (lhs.getScheduled_Date() == null || rhs.getScheduled_Date() == null)
            return 0;
        return lhs.getScheduled_Date().compareTo(rhs.getScheduled_Date());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of HashMap does not provide any order of the items. The ArrayList keep the order of added data. You should change your flow to have result as you expect.

This is the flow you need to have:

1. Acquire data in valid order
2. Create Mapping
3. Display

In your code you use method

`List<SalesCall> salescall = db.getAllSalescalls();`

If you have provided this data in demanded order then you will not have to sort them before mapping

`List<SalesCall> salesCallByDate = db.getSalesCallsAndSortBy(R.id.Date, R.id.Time);`

Then when you traverse this List and create mapping into map that is stored in new list the order will be maintain.

Comment: This is a great solution, never actually thought about it that way. I feel silly how simple it was. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` won't sort the data by key. Probably you're seeking for `TreeMap`.

But after reviewing more your code, you're doing this wrong. It would be better to use `List<SalesCall>` instead of `List<Map<String, String>>` to pass the data. Probably you will need that `SalesCall` class implements `Comparable` accordingly for your sort and if it will pass from different intents, it may also need to implement `Serializable`.

Basic sample for implementing `Comparable`:

```
public SalesCall implements Comparable<SalesCall> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(SalesCall another) {
        /* algoritm to sort by Date and Time fields */
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, The SalesCall is actually a class for the Data Base that the Data is being loaded from.

Comment: @M0NKEYRASH and the problem reusing that class is... Well, if you can't modify it, just provide a custom `Comparator`: `public class SalesCallDateComparator implements Comparator<SalesCall> { /* */ }`

Comment: Alright so I managed to modify the original class without any errors. I implemented a comparator that just compares the date at the moment. It looks like this (Check Edit) I still don't understand how It checks the date and then tells the listview that it should put it in that order. I don't think I implemented it correctly.